# Form data not getting entered in mail

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

when I submit this form, after entering some data, Gmail pops up but nothing is entered in it. What should I do so that the data I enter in the form gets entered in the email?

```
<form class="" action="mailto:exampl@gmail.com" method="post">

  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="form-label">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="name@example.com">
  </div>
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1" class="form-label">Example textarea</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
  </div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Don't use `mailto:` as a form action. It is [very very unreliable](http://isolani.co.uk/articles/mailto.html).

Comment: See the section headed "The Solution" in the link in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `name` attribute to each field, which will appear in the mail's body. It'll format itself as `mail={your_message}` and so on.

Your code becomes:

```
<form class="" action="mailto:exampl@gmail.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="form-label">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="name@example.com" name="email">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1" class="form-label">Example textarea</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3" name="message"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deathstalkersid/ro0an465/5/)

Comment: now data is getting entered but it is all messed up and some characters are getting changed like @ is getting changed to %40 why is it so?

Comment: Add `enctype="text/plain"` to your form tag. The unicode issue should be fixed. Updated the fiddle as well. The reason it changes is because by default a form URL encodes any input. So if you specify it to treat it as text, it won't do the encoding.